# how to fix ParserError: Expected primary expression under maticFarmAddress

Tags: solidity

ParserError: Expected primary expression.
--> bbcbank.sol:15:39:
|
15 | address public maticFarmAddress = <0x24920E62B2702c11011823E64387B8AB46C1c927>;
| ^

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
address public maticFarmAddress = 0x24920E62B2702c11011823E64387B8AB46C1c927;
```

Comment: Please add more explanation to your answer.

Comment: Dion Sheffield has following error: Expected Primary expression. and link to this incorrect expression, which is  address public maticFarmAddress = <0x24920E62B2702c11011823E64387B8AB46C1c927>;  So here we can see incorrect syntax where he uses <> to define address. Now i suggesting him to use my this expression without <>. So after all this manipulations code will work fine.